# messed up the python environment of my centOS server

Tags: python, linux

I accidentally messed up the python environment of my centOS server. My python3 soft link was linked to the anaconda path. Now I want to link the python3 soft link to the original /usr/bin/python3.7, but when running the python3 command, the following error message pops up.
`Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix> Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>] Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: Unable to get the locale encoding ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'`

I tried setting PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH via
`export PYTHONHOME="/usr/lib/python3.7" export PYTHONPATH /usr/bin`

Comment: Sorry, but fixing broken installations isn't a suitable topic here. Head over to e.g. superuser.com instead. Make sure to read their guidelines first though. Also, it would help if you provided infos about what you actually did in detail.